# Doctrine: Update Join?

Tags: join, symfony1, doctrine

Anyone know how to do an update with a join (i.e. update on two tables in one query) in Doctrine 1.2?

I spotted something obscure on a forum that hinted that this is not supported in 1.x but it was about as vague as it comes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the cleanest I could get it in the end, seems to do the job.

```
Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection()->execute("UPDATE JOIN QUERY GOES IN HERE");
```